# How to move JSplitPane's divider when I double-clicked it?

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

I want to move JSplitPane's divider to center if I double-click the divider.

So I added MouseListener to JSplitPane but it didn't work.

It works only when I double-clicked other JSplitPane's space without the divider.

Is there any way to work as I want?

Here is the code I failed

```
splitPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        //super.mouseClicked(e);
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(0.5);
    }
});
```

(it work same when I use MouseListener)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: In other words: try to write a **minimal** piece of code that shows the problem. Very often doing that will already tell you what is wrong about your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is that the JSplitPane itself does not recieve the click event.

Instead, the UI class of JSplitPane does.

This code works:

```
JSplitPane split = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, component1, component2);

    SplitPaneUI spui = split.getUI();
    if (spui instanceof BasicSplitPaneUI) {
        ((BasicSplitPaneUI) spui).getDivider().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                if (arg0.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    split.setDividerLocation(0.5);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @최혜정 You're welcome. :) Please consider accepting this answer if it was helpful to you, so that others who might have the same problem also know that it works.

Comment: Oh, I forgot it. Of course i'd like to accept your answer! :D